# How can I explain this shortened version of code in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know that the `preferredStyle` property on `UIAlertController` takes either `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` or `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.  When I see the example below, it seems it can be shortened by just using .Alert or .ActionSheet.  I'm trying to figure out the technical term for this shortcut so I can better explain its use to others, I would prefer not to say "Use the shortened version with a dot" if there is a better way.  Thank you very much.

Shortened

```
let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
```

Regular

```
let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet)
```

Comment: I _think_ that's an enum type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quote from [*The Swift Programming Language* > Language Guide > Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145) > Enumeration Syntax:

> Once `directionToHead` is declared as a `CompassPoint`, you can set it to a different `CompassPoint` value using a shorter dot syntax:
>
> ```
> directionToHead = .East
> ```

Honestly, calling it “shorter dot syntax” is probably going to be the clearest way to explain it to others.

But if you want to sound confusing, here's a quote from [*The Swift Programming Language* > Language Reference > Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID383) > Implicit Member Expression:

> An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an enumeration case or a type method, in a context where type inference can determine the implied type. It has the following form:
>
> > `.`<kbd>`member name`</kbd>

Comment: Nice answer, thank you.  Shorter dot syntax does seem like the easiest way to explain it.

Comment: The problem with this style is that code completion does not work so I avoid it.

Comment: Xcode's completion support for shorter dot syntax has improved a lot since Xcode 6, but is still lacking in some places.